# XCode update prevented by other account which left company

Tags: xcode, app-store, itunes

I want to update my xcode from appstore and wheni tried i was being thrown a message:
"**You have updates available for other accounts.Sign in to XXXX@gmail.com to update applications for that account.**"

I earlier installed the xcode on my mac using my colleagues apple ID and now i have no access to his account as he changed his password after leaving the organisation.

I tried to google and found some stackoverflow suggestions like index mechanism of sportlight.I was suggested to add Macintosh HD to the Privacy tab in spotlight preferences and close it.After a few minutes remove the Macintosh added earlier and found that spotlight re indexed all the contents. After following all the suggestions i am ending with the same message.

Could someone please help me in updating my xcode with my apple Id.I know that if i delete the xcode (reinstall) then it is possible to do so with my apple Id,which i am not willing to do.

PLz help..Tnx in advance.

Comment: The XCode is obtained via the app store using your (former) colleagues ID?
There is no way you can update that without his credentials, you have to remove the application and install it with you own account again.

Answer (score 6):

This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/73078/1383) might help you out. Looks like you can tell XCode to forget who downloaded an app.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting some issue with iTunes as I definitely have updated in the past with the same apple ID.  I tried every possible apple ID that I have, (only 2) and I still had the message that I had to log in with the correct apple ID.

Had no choice but to delete xcode and reinstall from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple answer to it...
Go to /Users/Your_User_Name/Library/Caches/ using Terminal app
And delete all the files inside it.
Restart your mac and try then.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps ::
1. Open System Preferences > Spotlight

1. Under the Privacy tab. Add your Macintosh HD (or whatever your main hard disk is called) to the list.
2. Close the window. Wait a few seconds. Then go back to Spotlight settings and remove the entry you just added.
3. The spotlight index should now begin to re-index completely. (A dot will fade-in/out inside the Spotlight icon in the taskbar)
4. Wait for it to finish and then launch the Mac App Store. You should now see updates in the Updates tab.

This worked for me. Please share if you face any problem in comment section.